# Unable to chroot /mnt/sysimage

Tags: rhel, chroot, rescuemode

I'm working on a RH 7.3 with some issues on the partitions so It doesn't boot properly and goes in emergency mode. I booted the machine from an RH 7.3 iso and I need to extract an sosreport in Rescue mode but I have the following errors:

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/sh': No such file or directory
```

So I use the following command as in the page https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43133:

```
ln -s bash /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh
```

but I'm getting the error message:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: symlinking to a file outside the chroot will not and can not work.  the linked file is inaccessible inside the chroot, and the symlink is followed with the chroot dir as /.   copy the file instead, e.g. `cp -a /bin/bash /mnt/sysimage/bin/`.   Note that a symlink like `ln -s /bin/bash /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh` will now work because there **is** now a /bin/bash inside the chroot

Comment: BTW, the chroot will also need its own copy of any shared libs required by bash.  and lots of other stuff if you want to do anything useful inside the chroot.

Comment: I can't copy because the directory bin in /mnt/sysimage/ doesn't exist

Comment: that's what `mkdir` is for.  mkdir then cp.   BTW that explains your "No such file or directory" error message - you can't create a symlink in a non-existent directory, either.

Comment: To anyone with a similar problem: Note that `/mnt/sysimage` being completely empty when in RHEL rescue mode suggests that the start-up of the rescue mode failed to mount the installation that should be rescued, suggesting a major problem with its root filesystem. There should also have been a message dialog from the rescue mode start-up, indicating the failure to mount the root filesystem. You should first try and investigate the state of the problematic root filesystem without chrooting, and mount it manually and *then* chroot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The link is not public. But most likely you have to use the full path to the bash shell (or be in the folder /bin). Try:

```
ln -s /bin/bash /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh
```

Comment: I already tried that command but It goes in error because the directory /mnt/sysimage/ is empty.

Comment: So, you solved the problem?

Comment: unfortunatelly not. I can't proceed because that directory is empty.

Comment: You might want to update the question with the current status. Commands you tried, error messages,...

Comment: The command ln -s /bin/bash /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh shows the error message: ln: failed to create symbolic link /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh: No such file or directory. I have the directory /mnt/sysimage/ empty. This is the current status.